# Javascript changing form elements

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to brush up on my JS and I want to have it so the user can put in their first and last name and two numbers. When they click the button, I want the text to change to, "Hello *Name*! Your sum is *number*!"

My code isn't working, would someone be able to tell me where my issue is?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>JS Review</title>

<style>
    body{background: #8ADFB6; font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";}
    #container{background: white; padding: 30px; width: 760px; margin: 0 auto;}
    #output{
        padding: 10px; margin: 10px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

    <h1>Using Form Elements with Javascript</h1>


    <p>We can utilize user input to create feedback</p>
    First Name: <input id="first">
    Last Name: <input id="last">
    <p></p>
    Number 1: <input id="num1">
    Number 2: <input id="num2">
    <p></p>
    <button onClick="Respond()">Respond</button>

    <div id="output"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function myFunction(){

        var a = document.getElementById("first").value;
        var b = document.getElementById("last").value;
        var c = document.getElementById("num1").value;
        var d = document.getElementById("num2").value;
        var n= document.getElementById("sum").value;

        var n= c + d;

        document.getElementById("Respond").innerHTML="Respond";

    }



    document.getElementById("Respond").innerHTML = "Hello! Your sum is !";


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see a function called `Respond()`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Comment: @epascarello Console is bae <3

Answer (score 0):

1. Your button click handler referenced to a function called `Respond()` but the actual function you want to reference to is called `myFunction()` (or vice-versa).
2. The input values of `Number 1` and `Number 2` that you have retrieved are strings. You need to parse the input values of `Number 1` and `Number 2` input elements (convert the strings to integers) to be able to perform mathematical calculations with them.
3. You must set the `innerHTML` of `#output`, not `#Respond` to the result. You can either use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with [String Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation) or basic concatenation to combine your result, first name, last name and the `"Hello! Your sum is !"`string.

--

The **concatenation** approach would look like this:

```
"a " + someVariableName + " is a fruit that has vitamin " + someOtherVariable
```

The **template literals** and **string interpolation** approach would look like this:

```
`a ${someVariableName} is a fruit that has vitamin ${someOtherVariable}`
```

--

4. Avoid using inline on* handlers (onclick, oninput, etc) and instead, use an event listener in your JavaScript itself.

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** where I parsed the values and used string interpolation to output the sentence with the result when the button is clicked:

```js
/* JavaScript */

function myFunction(){

  var a = document.getElementById("first").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("last").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var d = document.getElementById("num2").value;

  var n= parseInt(c) + parseInt(d);

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = `Hello ${a} ${b}! Your sum is ${n}!`;

}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

First Name: <input id="first">
Last Name: <input id="last">
<p></p>
Number 1: <input id="num1">
Number 2: <input id="num2">
<p></p>
<button>Respond</button>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: @newgirl456 Glad I could help :) Do mark this as the correct answer and upvote it if it helped you solve your issue. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few issues.

First, you are trying to do math but are using string values. You can't do that otherwise they are going to concat and make 3 + 1 = 31 instead of 4. You can fix that by parsing the float, now one thing I would recommend is confirming they are numbers so you aren't doing invalid parsing.

```
if(isNaN(c) || isNaN(d) {
     alert('Invalid Input');
}else{
    var n= parseFloat(c) + parseFloat(d);
    document.getElementById("Respond").innerHTML = "Hello! Your sum is " + n;
}
```

---

Next, you are calling function respond but that function doesn't exist. What does exist is myFunction so you have a few options.

Either update this line in your JS to use Respond as the function name:

```
function myFunction(){
```

should be:

```
function Respond(){
```

Or update your HTML button to use the right function name:

```
 <button onClick="Respond()">Respond</button>
```

Should be:

```
 <button onClick="myFunction()">Respond</button>
```

---

Next, you are looking for an element with the ID respond but that element doesn't exist. Once again you are using the wrong ID. You need to be using output there.

This line:

```
    document.getElementById("Respond").innerHTML = "Hello! Your sum is !";
```

Should be:

```
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Hello! Your sum is " + n + "!";
```

---

Next, you are trying to get the value of something with the ID of sum but it doesn't exist at all.

Just straight up remove this line:

```
        var n= document.getElementById("sum").value;
```

---

Finally, why is your value updater outside of the function call? That updater needs to be inside of the function with what is actually getting the values. If you don't you are never going to be able to update the string.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>JS Review</title>

<style>
    body{background: #8ADFB6; font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";}
    #container{background: white; padding: 30px; width: 760px; margin: 0 auto;}
    #output{
        padding: 10px; margin: 10px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

    <h1>Using Form Elements with Javascript</h1>


    <p>We can utilize user input to create feedback</p>
    First Name: <input id="first">
    Last Name: <input id="last">
    <p></p>
    Number 1: <input id="num1">
    Number 2: <input id="num2">
    <p></p>
    <button onClick="myFunction()">Respond</button>

    <div id="output"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function myFunction(){

        var a = document.getElementById("first").value;
        var b = document.getElementById("last").value;
        var c = document.getElementById("num1").value;
        var d = document.getElementById("num2").value;
        if(isNaN(c) || isNaN(d)) {
          alert('Invalid Input');
        }else{
          var n= parseFloat(c) + parseFloat(d);
          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Hello! Your sum is " + n;

        }

    }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**So while I have given you quite a bit here to look at, you really need to take a minute to review your code. You had quite a few issues that could have been resolved if you had just slowed down and read what you were doing.**

Answer (score -1):

`document.getElementById("num1").value;` returns a string.

You need to change it to a number if you want to do math.

```
parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
```

If someone types in a non-number, this will still fail because you need to validate your inputs as part of the process.